# How to convert XWalkView page to image?

Tags: android, crosswalk

I am using Crosswalk library instead of regular WebView. I need to print receipt in printer where I send bytes. For this purpose I want to convert page to image then send print it out. This is what I tried:

```
public void onLoadFinished(XWalkView view, String url) {
    super.onLoadFinished(view, url);
    Log.d(TAG, "Load Finished:" + url);

    View v = view.getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/"  + "page.jpg" );
        if ( fos != null ) {
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos );
            fos.close();
        }
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        System.out.println("-----error--"+e);
    }
}
```

I am getting this:
[image]

How to capture page to image?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks using Crosswalk.
You can try this API:

```
/**
* Capture a bitmap of visible content.
* @param callback callback to call when the bitmap capture is done.
* @since 6.0
*/
public void captureBitmapAsync(XWalkGetBitmapCallback callback)
```